# Force VS2012 to publish empty directory when publishing a WCF service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, publish

I am using ELMAH in my WCF service and I want it to write XML files to a folder named ErroLogs. This folder is in the project.

When I publish (FileSystem) however this folder is not published and I have no properties to say "Copy Always".

Right now I have added a text file inside and set that to "Copy Always" and this effectively forces the folder to be published. ***So this is a workaround.***

Is there a way to force publication of the empty folder, or must I use this text file workaround?

Comment: As far as I have used that's the way to go. Else a targets file or powershell script may be considered

Comment: possible duplicate of [publish empty directories to a web application in VS2010 web project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257660/publish-empty-directories-to-a-web-application-in-vs2010-web-project)